# vb.net chart - coloring stackedcolumns

Tags: vb.net, charts

I want to set a color for each stackedcolumn in my chart.
I used the `DataBindCrossTable` Method but i cant figure out what to pass with the "otherFields" at the end, like i did with the label

(dt is my datatable)

```
Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dt)
    Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dv, "Counter", "Tag", "ItemValue", "Label=Tag, Color=ItemColor")

    For Each cs As Charting.Series In Chart1.Series
        cs.ChartType = Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
    Next
```

[msdn link to data point class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapoint_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)